# Is there a way to download the auto generated subtitles of videos in a private / public YouTube playlist?

Tags: download, youtube, subtitles, youtube-dl, playlists

I found this [cool Reddit link](https://old.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/coht2b/download_subtitles_from_a_youtube_playlist_windows/) here which basically does what the title says, but this stuff felt a bit confusing to me. Can somebody please suggest if there's a better way to download the automatically generated YouTube captions / subtitles if you want to call those that from a playlist which can be either public or private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script you linked to is overkill because it tries to grab subtitles from several videos in a playlist without taking advantage of the fact that, for several years now, `youtube-dl` has  accepted playlists as input in addition to videos. Regardless, what you want can be done in a line of code.

1. Download and install the latest version of [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#installation) for your operating system.
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   youtube-dl <URL-to-video-or-playlist> --skip-download --write-auto-sub
   ```

   *If you want the video in addition to the subtitle file remove the `--skip-download` option.*
3. Once the files have been downloaded, you'll find them in the folder you ran the command in. They will likely be `.vtt` files but could also be `.srt` or other common subtitle formats.

Comment: That worked fine, thanks, Hashim!